# Finding largest number in array

Tags: c++, arrays

Can somebody please tell me what is wrong with my program? My program is supposed find the largest value in `int i[]` but when I run it, it asks me to enter 11 numbers and the largest number of the 11 numbers is displayed instead.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
    int i[] =
    {
        88, 67, 90, 12, 34, 65, 100, 78, 56, 77, 85, //bus 8
        98, 34, 67, 98, 67, 45, 67, 23, 45, 67, 89, //bus15
        88, 67, 90, 12, 34, 65, 100, 78, 56, 77, 85, //22
        98, 34, 67, 98, 67, 45, 67, 23, 45, 67, 89, //23
    };
    int j;
    int number,largest;
    largest=0;
    for(j=0;j<11;j++)
    {
        scanf_s("%d",&number);
        if(number>largest)largest=number;
    }
    printf("Largest=%d\n",largest);
}
```

How do I adjust the program so that it will find the largest value in `int i[]`?.

Comment: Try setting `number` to different values in `i` throughout the loop. Perhaps something like `number = i[j];`

Comment: What is the `scanf_s` for?

Comment: What you're looking for is debugging help. You should start by debugging by printing (print your variables and possibly some checkpoints)

Comment: Use [std::max_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding max value in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719978/finding-max-value-in-an-array)

Comment: "My program is to find out the largest value in int i" - then why do you have the loop where you get user input and keep track of the largest of those? "but when i run the program, the program ask me to enter 11 numbers and the largest number of the 11 numbers are displayed" - this makes it sound like you didn't write the code you provided. That is what the code is written to do, how can this be surprising to you? If you did indeed write this, what have you tried so far to count the max element in i? Even then, be sure to search first before asking, there are already answers to this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `std::max_element` from `<algorithm>`:

```
#include <algorithm>

int i[] = { 1, 84, 11, 31 };

// for C++11 and later:
int max = *std::max_element(std::begin(i), std::end(i));

// for C++03 or earlier:
int max2 = *std::max_element(i, i + (sizeof(i) / sizeof(*i)));
```

or if your array is static, you can just use an C++11 initializer list:

```
auto i = { 1, 84, 11, 31 };
int max = std::max(i);
int max2 = std::max({ 1, 84, 11, 31 });
```

**PS:** A live example using these methods can be found [here](https://ideone.com/0gnaoL).

Comment: Thanks!! Manage to solve with std: : max element

Answer (score 4):

in `<algorithm>`:

```
std::cout << *std::max_element(std::begin(i), std::end(i)) << std::endl;
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/kLbMUX)

or if you use an initializer_list to contains your numbers you may directly use `std::max`:

```
auto i =
{
    88, 67, 90, 12, 34, 65, 100, 78, 56, 77, 85,
    98, 34, 67, 98, 67, 45, 67, 23, 45, 67, 89,
    88, 67, 90, 12, 34, 65, 100, 78, 56, 77, 85,
    98, 34, 67, 98, 67, 45, 67, 23, 45, 67, 89,
};
std::cout << std::max(i) << std::endl;
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/hLLA6Z)

Answer (score 1):

you must initialized number and largest to 0;

```
number = 0;
largest = 0;
```

or it will be a random number saves in position in memory.

try

```
int largerst = 0;

for(int j=0;j < sizeof i;j++) {
if (i[j] > largest) largest = i[j];
}
cout << largest << endl;
```

Comment: Both get initialized before they're read from, this is not the issue.