# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable ' ' was corrupted

Tags: arrays

Im making a program that supposed to take a set of numbers from a txt file and display them in arrays. Every time I try debugging, only the first number is shown then the prompt "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'mygrade' was corrupted." is shown.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;


int main(){     
const int SIZE = 10;
int i;

ifstream grades;
grades.open("grade.txt");


double mygrade[SIZE] = { 0 };

for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++);
grades >> mygrade[i]; 

for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++);
cout << mygrade[i] << endl;

    grades.close();

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger. You will be surprised at what you see executing.

Comment: I did, it also says Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'mygrade' was corrupted." is shown.

Comment: So you didn't notice that `grades >> mygrade[i];` executes **after** the `for` loop instead of during it? And did you notice what the value of `i` is when you do the `grades >> mygrade[i];`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Out of bounds array index due to misplaced semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719978/finding-max-value-in-an-array)